# Not getting desired current with nordic power profiler when using the PPK2_API

Tags: python, measurement

I am also using the ppk2_api to get the current. But the number of samples read is sometimes 1024, 2048 or 4096. Also the average current of this many samples is very less (<1 uA), which is not at all desirable. On the  other hand, the nrfConnect application gives the expected current.

I know that the finest sampling rate of PPK can be 10 usec, and if we take a one minute run, we get around 60,00,000 samples. But I am not able to figure out how to set those configurations using PPK2_API.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

The average current of all samples is very less (<1uA). The expected currents are in order of 10s of uA in sleep state and in order of mA in active state.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.